# EAN 13 scanned incorrect in Mobile vision

Tags: mobile, vision

When we scan EAN 13 barcode form mobile vision the barcode received is incorrect.

What can we do fix this.

Comment: I am trying to integrate the same. But it doesnt detect bar codes. Did you find any solution?